# Avoiding the Generalized Variance Formula for the NYC Housing and Vacancy Survey

Tags: r, stata, sas, survey, census

I am attempting to devise a replication-based survey design that closely replicates a taylor-series design used by the US Government publication - where I do not have access to all of the `CLUSTER` variables.

The US Census Bureau publishes a triennial survey of New York City dwellings called the NYCHVS.  In their official documentation, they recommend that analysts use a [generalized variance formula](http://www.census.gov/hhes/www/housing/nychvs/2008/S&A_2008.pdf#page=11), which is obviously a computational nightmare - since everything needs to be calculated by hand.  However, they also publish a series of [table packages](http://www.census.gov/hhes/www/housing/nychvs/2008/contract_items_2008.xls) that contain standard errors calculated through a Taylor-Series Linearization method.  When I contacted them about how to reproduce their statistics, they said

> The appropriate variables for him to use would be borough and segment.

The variable `borough` is available in the data set, but the variable `segment` is not - and they will not release it due to confidentiality concerns.

I am able to precisely reproduce their means and medians - the `hhweight` variable is sufficient for that.

I have tried constructing my own replicate weights (just a matrix of `0` and `1`), but my standard errors either come in far, far too big or basically no different from a `simple random sample` (and so far too small).

Obviously, I will never match the US Government's statistics perfectly, but if I've only got one of two `CLUSTER` variables, is there a decent way I could calibrate and create a survey design that would get me close to the right answer?

Comment: i gave up and created [a fake method](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/new%20york%20city%20housing%20and%20vacancy%20survey%20%28nychvs%29)